# Guessing game only ever thinks the guess is too high

Tags: python

Does anyone know why this function only prints out that the guess is too high? Ideas on how to fix?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random
def goguess():
    HighNumber= random.randint(1,100)
    LowNumber= random.randint(1,HighNumber-1)
    answer = random.randint(LowNumber+1,HighNumber)
    guesses = 0
    print ('I have a number between', LowNumber, 'and', HighNumber, 'inclusive.')
    guess = raw_input('guess:')
    while guess != answer:
        if guess > answer:
            print(guess, 'is too high.')
            guesses+=1
            print('Guess:', guesses)
            guess = raw_input('guess:')
        if guess < answer:
            print(guess, 'is too low')
            guesses+=1
            print('Guess:',guesses)
            guess = raw_input('guess:')
    if guess == answer:
        print ('Right! My number is', answer,'! You guessed in ',guesses, 'guesses!')
```

Comment: This isn't related to your current problem, but your program will crash if `HighNumber` has a value of 1. Then `LowNumber` tries to assign to `random.randint(1,0)`, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert their input to `int`

```
guess = int(raw_input('guess:'))
```

Otherwise you are comparing a `str` to an `int`, and the `str` will always be greater.

```
>>> '3' > 7
True
>>> int('3') > 7
False
```

In Python 3.x you would have seen the issue in a more obvious manner, as you cannot compare these types like this anymore

```
>>> '3' > 7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    '3' > 7
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess has to be an integer in order to be compared to an integer. raw_input returns a string of the integer. Strings can be converted to integers using int(). After

```
guess = raw_input('Guess')
```

You can store

```
intguess = int(guess)
```